# Fractions with python

Tags: python, fractions

I'm trying to do this calculation:

```
from fractions import Fraction 
z=4
x=Float(Fraction(1+math.pi,1+2*z**2))
```

But this results in the following error:

```
TypeError: both arguments should be Rational instances
```

If I change pi value for integer value works. But if I use a decimal value shows me that error.

Any idea?

Regards
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the documented for the [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module:

> The [two argument constructor] requires that `numerator` and `denominator` are instances of [numbers.Rational](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Rational).

In your snippet, `1+math.pi` is a `float`, not an instance of `numbers.Rational`, hence the `TypeError`.